# objectPoints in solvePnP method?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an **object(fix)** to detect and track.

I have its `image_points` which are necessary for the *slovePnP algorithm*.

But the first parameter is the object coordinates matrix,

I'm confused about it.

How can we generate an object_point matrix of an object in the camera frame in real-time?

```
 ret, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints, box, camera_matrix, camera_distortion, rvec, tvec,flags = flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure 3d coordinates of points in objects local coordinate system, and then detect them in image. And only after that pnp will give you transformations. Check this:

https://www.learnopencv.com/head-pose-estimation-using-opencv-and-dlib/

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/10/17/head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-opengl-revisited-w-code/